# How to download and view images from SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem. I want to download and view in browser images from a SQL Server table. I don't know how to do.

My code:

```
public partial class IndexForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string CurrentUser = User.Identity.Name;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            if (CurrentUser == null || CurrentUser == "" || CurrentUser == " ")
            {
                //Zaprzeczenie w if'ie nie działa...
            }
            else if (CurrentUser != null || CurrentUser != "" || CurrentUser != " ")
            { 
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    GridView GridView1 = LoginView3.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
                    cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = @CurrentUser";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@CurrentUser"].Value = User.Identity.Name;
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    con.Open();

                    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Name, Data, ContentType from tblFiles where Id=@Id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;

                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                    contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload FileUpload1 = LoginView3.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        string email = User.Identity.Name;

        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = "insert into tblFiles values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data, @email)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

This is my table in the SQL Server database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblFiles] 
(
    [id]          INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [ContentType] NVARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL,
    [Data]        VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [email]       VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL
);
```

How to download and view images from SQL Server table?

This code doesn't work:

```
foreach (string strfile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files")))
```

and

```
public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        byte[] fileContent = null;
        string mimeType = "";
        string fileName = "";

        const string connect = @"Server=your_servername;Database=your_database;User 
        Id=user_id;password=user_password;";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            var qry = "SELECT FileContent, MimeType, FileName FROM FileStore WHERE ID 
            = @ID";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

            conn.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                rdr.Read();

                fileContent = (byte[])rdr["FileContent"];
                mimeType = rdr["MimeType"].ToString();
                fileName = rdr["FileName"].ToString();
            }
        }

        return File(fileContent, mimeType, fileName);
    }
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what this code is all about? All snnipets seem to be doing a different thing pointing to a different database table

Comment: I must doing upload, download files to SQL Database and now I must view files(images) in browser. Look at BindGrid() this function have good pointing to database table. Code at the end of post is exemple and doesn't work if I also change this code.

Comment: Doesn't work --> I can't display images in browser...

Comment: You are vaguely aware that the HTML you generate (which you say nothing about) is quite critical? You likely do a serious mistake on the HTML level (i.e. generated HTML) and just do not show us that.

Comment: @BotWtest mate, this is really confusing you say you want to "display images in browser" without even specifying what exactly it means. However, your code is NOT doing so, your code is setting the `content-disposition` header in the response indicating (usually) that the browser will prompt a user to download a file...obviously, this DOESN'T "display" the image. Can you be more specific what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use an `HttpHandler` in order to transform back your byte array.

```
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
         int id = context.Request.QueryString.Get("ID");
         SqlDataReader rdr;
         byte[] fileContent = null;
         const string connect = @"Server=your_servername;Database=your_database;User 
         Id=user_id;password=user_password;";

         using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
         {
            var qry = "SELECT FileContent, MimeType, FileName FROM FileStore WHERE ID = @ID";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            conn.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
              rdr.Read();
              context.Response.Clear();
              context.Response.ContentType = rdr["MimeType"].ToString();
              context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["FileContent"]);
              context.Response.End();
            }
         }
      }

      public bool IsReusable
      {
        get
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Once your image handler is created, register it in your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  . . .
  <system.webServer>
    . . .
    <handlers>
      <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="Assembly.ImageHandler,Assembly" />
      . . .
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  . . .
</configuration>
```

Then add the route to ignore in order to handle the file

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{handler}.ashx");
```

Finally, you will be able to display the image by calling it from your html

```
<img src="~/ImageHandler.ashx?ID=@YourItemId"/>
```

Regards.

Comment: a generic handler doesn't need any sort of registration, it plugs in to the ASP.NET pipeline by default