# Retrieve Image (byte array) from sql database and show the Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

In my wpf mvvm application I write a code for image upload and save to database.
The code is working fine and the image save to the data base.
Here I need to retrieve the image from the database and show in a Image box.Here is my Insert code

```
public void Upload(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
        dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*.jpg)|*.png;*.jpg";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            UploadText = filename;
            FileStream FS = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
            FS.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FS.Length));
            UploadLogo = img;
            Stream reader = File.OpenRead(filename);
            System.Drawing.Image photo = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream((Stream)reader);
            MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream();
            photo.Save(finalStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            // translate to image source
            PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(finalStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                                                BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            ClientLogo = decoder.Frames[0]; ;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

how can I convert this byte data to image

Thanks in advance

Comment: Answered this a few weeks ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862980/how-to-download-and-view-images-from-sql-server-table/25863338

Answer (score 3):

**Use Below Code**

```
            object binaryData = ("select ImageDataColunm from table where id=yourID");// use your code to retrive image from database and store it into 'object' data type
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])binaryData;
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            AspImageID.ImageUrl= "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

**EDIT:** and you can [See the Solution here fro WPF](http://cromwellhaus.com/2007/07/binding-to-the-byte-of-an-image-in-wpf/)

Comment: Hello I am checking.But it is not working..

I am using image tool in wpf.so it need the image source.
AspImageID.ImageUrl is string

Comment: in my code Uploadlogo having the byte from database
This is my imagesource property

 private ImageSource _clientlogo;
        public ImageSource ClientLogo
        {
            get
            {
                return _clientlogo;
            }
            set
            {
                _clientlogo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ClientLogo");
            }
        }

Comment: @Arun - see the updated answer link

Comment: Anybody know why "data:image/png;base64," is removed before the image is stored and re-added when it is read?